# Ajax form data not sending with multiple object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, object

I have faced a problem. I need to submit data using form and my previous storage data both are together. When I sent `cart` data is submitting properly but my `form_data` is showing empty. If I used this code for submitting only form then it works fine. How can I send both data?

```
data : form_data,
contentType: false,
cache: false,
processData:false
```

**AJAX:**

```
jQuery( "#chackOutBillingIfor" ).submit(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var products = JSON.stringify(cart);
    var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=chackOut",  
        data: {productInfo:JSON.stringify(cart), json_2:JSON.stringify(form_data)},
        type: 'POST'
    })
});
```

Comment: you can append field whic is curruntly no send with form data like formData.append('user_ids', JSON.stringify(arr));

Comment: where is your cart data ? you are using in this line `var products = JSON.stringify(cart);`

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
var datastring = jQuery("#chackOutBillingIfor").serialize();

jQuery.ajax({
      url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=chackOut",  
      data: {
              productInfo:JSON.stringify(cart), 
              billingInfo:datastring,
            },
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
});
</script>



add_action( 'wp_ajax_chackOut', 'my_ajax_foobar_handler' );

function my_ajax_foobar_handler() {
    // Make your response and echo it.

    $params = array();
    parse_str(stripslashes($_POST['billingInfo']), $params);
    print_r($params );
    // Don't forget to stop execution afterward.
    wp_die();
}
```